# direct reference to app.ico icon - NO EXTRACT

Tags: c#, reference, icons, c#-3.0, embed

I have a C# project. I choose the .ico file for it in property so it automatically added the .ico into the list from the "solution explorer".

I am using a "notifyIcon", and want to change the icon programmatically.
example a notifyIcon red when program is busy and green when free.
So i know i have to add a new embed resource for the second ico. but how to access to the already existing one that is the application ico?

i would like "something like"

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = AppName.greenico.ico; //default app ico
notifyIcon1.Icon = AppName.redico.ico;   //ico ill add as embed resource i guess
```

is that possible? i saw some strange ExtractIco thingy... But i am sure its possible to reference straight to something already embed ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a really really easy solution.
First: Change "Build" properties of the two icons in "Solution Explorer" to "Embedded Ressource".

now in your code just set the two icons as variables:

```
public Icon greenIco = new Icon(typeof(MainFormName), "GreenIco.ico");
public Icon redIco = new Icon(typeof(MainFormName), "RedIco.ico");
```

then to use them, easy so:

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = greenIco;
```

as simple as that.
Hope it'll help someone else a day.